# How can I see files inside a Ruby .gem?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

Once I have installed a Ruby gem I know that I can see the files inside the gem by using `gem contents <my_gem>`. But how can I see the contents of a gem without installing it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### with `gem unpack`

You can use the `gem unpack` command to extract the contents of a `.gem` file into a directory. Assuming you have some_file.gem:

```
gem unpack some_file.gem
```

### with `tar`

If you want to list the gem's contents *without* unpacking it, you can use `tar` (a `.gem` file is just a `.tar` file with a specific format).

```
tar --to-stdout -xf some_file.gem data.tar.gz | tar -zt
```

Here's a longer explanation of how this works:

```
# Download a .gem file
$ gem fetch json_pure -v '2.0.3'
Fetching: json_pure-2.0.3.gem (100%)
Downloaded json_pure-2.0.3

# List the contents of the gem
# You can see that it contains separate files for metadata, the gem files, and a checksum
$ tar -tf json_pure-2.0.3.gem
metadata.gz
data.tar.gz
checksums.yaml.gz

# Extract just the data.tar.gz file, then unzip and list the contents of *that* file.
#   --to-stdout so we can pipe it to another command
#   -x extract
#   -f file
#
# Then:
#   -z use gunzip to decompress the .tar.gz file
#   -t list the contents of the archive
tar --to-stdout -xf json_pure-2.0.3.gem data.tar.gz | tar -zt
./tests/test_helper.rb
.gitignore
.travis.yml
CHANGES.md
Gemfile
...
```

In most cases `gem unpack` is probably what you want. The main benefit to the `tar` command above is that it doesn't create any new directories or actually unpack the files. It might also be useful if you don't have rubygems installed.